# Do Sly Flourish and Night Stalker stack?

Tags: dnd-4e, rogue, assassin

Two-part question, roughly in the same category.

1. Since Guild Training is a Hybrid feat for Rogue/Assassins, is it legal or fair to take both Guild Training abilities burning two feats?
2. Sly Flourish with Night Stalker: Guild Training.

**Sly Flourish:** Hit: 1[W] + Dex mod + Cha mod

**Night Stalker:** + Cha mod damage against any target that is adjacent to none of your enemies.

With both, do you get double the Cha mod in damage?

Answer (score 10):

To answer your second question first:

***NO.*** In this case you do not. You missed a very important piece of the hybrid version of this feat (emphasis mine):

"You gain a bonus to damage rolls with **assassin powers and assassin paragon path powers** equal to your Charisma modifier against any target that is adjacent to none of your enemies." - [Dragon 385](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/class.aspx?id=641)

You don't get the bonus here becuase Sly Flourish is a rogue power.

As for your first. You may normally only take Hybrid Talent one time. However, if you select no paragon path you get it a second time. However, you many not take the same talent you've already taken. In this case "Guild Training" is the talent and the guild is a selection under that talent. Thus you may not take both guilds because you can't take "Guild Training" twice. (The online character builder confirms this).